# Accessing the Nest api https://developer-api.nest.com results in SSL errors

Tags: ssl, nest-api

When accessing the Nest API from my java app to return the devices, I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

The same URL (of the form)

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/devices?auth=<access_token_ommited_here>
```

Works fine from my browser. I suspect I'm missing a cert. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: [I'm seeing exactly the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415551/remote-host-closed-connection-during-handshake-with-nest-api) from the Force.com platform. Could you post information about your Java version, and the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your SSL library is using TLSv1 or higher security.  If it's defaulting to SSLv3 or lower, the server will reject the connection.

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use TLSv1.1 to avoid strange SSL behaviour, the initial request would setup SSL correctly, but subsequent requests to the 307 redirected URL would fail SSL. Not 100% it is working perfectly yet but seems to be more stable.

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");